# Problem in displaying thumbnail images

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have created 3 movieClips and I added into another movieClip container named as **mc**.

```
for(i = 0;i<3;i++)
{
    imgBox = new box();
    mc.addChild(imgBox);
    imgBox.name = "box" + i;
}
```

**xml** image names are **image1.jpg, image2.jpg and imag3.jpg**
and have stored in **thumbArray**.

```
for(i = 0;i<thumbArray.length; i++)
    {
        thumbLoader = new Loader();
        thumbLoader.load(new URLRequest(thumbArray[i]));
            thumbLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onThumbLoaded);

    }
```

and I have loaded.

```
int count = -1;
function onThumbLoaded (e:Event):void
{
    count++;
    var img:Bitmap = Bitmap(e.target.content);
    MovieClip(mc.getChildByName("box" +count)).addChild(img);
}
```

finally everthing loaded, but the display seaquence like this  **image3, image1 and image2**. I want to have the seaquence **image1, image2 and imag3**.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have no control over the speed at which each load occurs, so there is no guarantee that the first loader will complete first etc.  Your best approach will probably to name the loaders, and use the name to reference the target.  Something like this:

```
for(i = 0;i<thumbArray.length; i++)
{
    thumbLoader = new Loader();
    //assign a name that matches the target box name, with "Loader" on the end
    thumbLoader.name = "box" + i + "Loader";
    thumbLoader.load(new URLRequest(thumbArray[i]));
    thumbLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onThumbLoaded);
}

function onThumbLoaded (e:Event):void
{
    var img:Bitmap = Bitmap(e.target.content);
    //slice the "Loader" off the name
    var loadName:String = e.target.name.slice(0,-6);
    MovieClip(mc.getChildByName(loadName)).addChild(img);
}
```

Comment: Why do it has no control? Is there any reason behind?

Comment: Load operations are performed asynchronously, so in theory the smallest image will load first.  If you want to have more control you can try using a sequential loader, which there are several scripts available for.  I personally prefer [Greensock's LoaderMax](http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/), which gives you an immense amount of control, and can be configured to load sequentially or to prioritise different loaders first.